# Fire base native ads not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, admob, native-ads

Am trying to use admob native ads express
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express

Downloaded the sample app from github.
(https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExpressExample)
 But the app not showing native ads. I spent a lot of time to find the issue but i failed.
Anyone facing the same issue? or have any ways to display it.

Here is the logcat

```
06-15 21:07:29.539    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-15 21:07:29.689    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
06-15 21:07:29.689    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
06-15 21:07:29.689    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
06-15 21:07:29.869    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/ActivityThread﹕ Pub com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample.firebaseinitprovider: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
06-15 21:07:29.959    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-15 21:07:29.969    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx.getNoBackupFilesDir
06-15 21:07:29.969    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 358: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
06-15 21:07:29.969    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
06-15 21:07:30.029    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
06-15 21:07:30.029    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-15 21:07:30.079    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzan
06-15 21:07:30.079    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 267 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zze;
06-15 21:07:30.079    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
06-15 21:07:30.089    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzk
06-15 21:07:30.089    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 497: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-15 21:07:30.089    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
06-15 21:07:30.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/FA﹕ App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
06-15 21:07:30.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/FA﹕ To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
06-15 21:07:30.179    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.zzg
06-15 21:07:30.179    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpv;
06-15 21:07:30.179    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0010
06-15 21:07:30.879    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
06-15 21:07:30.879    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/FirebaseInitProvider﹕ FirebaseApp initialization successful
06-15 21:07:30.959    9609-9644/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample V/GoogleSignatureVerifier﹕ com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found:
    MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
    EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
    bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
    MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
    FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
    cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
    LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
    dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
    sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
    URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
    qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
    gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
    VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
    A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
    4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
    zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
    yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
    KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
    Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
    MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
06-15 21:07:30.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
06-15 21:07:30.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
06-15 21:07:30.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14515: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
06-15 21:07:30.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-15 21:07:30.999    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
06-15 21:07:30.999    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14519: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-15 21:07:30.999    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14410: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 573: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 595: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-15 21:07:31.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-15 21:07:31.899    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method dah.a
06-15 21:07:31.899    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 1659: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
06-15 21:07:31.899    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0072
06-15 21:07:31.949    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method iek.a
06-15 21:07:31.949    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1063: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-15 21:07:31.949    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
06-15 21:07:31.959    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method iek.s
06-15 21:07:31.959    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 383 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Liek;
06-15 21:07:31.959    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method iei.a
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 792: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00f4
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: access denied from Liei; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 521
06-15 21:07:32.129    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0113
06-15 21:07:32.149    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ChimeraCfgMgr﹕ Reading stored module config
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 612 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 611 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 612 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
06-15 21:07:32.289    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
06-15 21:07:32.309    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.309    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 613 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
06-15 21:07:32.309    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0264 at 0x17 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0263 at 0x26 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
06-15 21:07:32.329    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0264 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.is64BitRuntime
06-15 21:07:32.379    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ChimeraFileApk﹕ Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
06-15 21:07:32.379    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/ChimeraFileApk﹕ Classloading successful, but code may not be optimized. It will either run in fallback (interpreted mode) or the odex has been found and isDexOptNeeded is misreporting a failure.
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createDisplayContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createDisplayContext
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 966: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDisplayContext (Landroid/view/Display;)Landroid/content/Context;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColor, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColor
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1087: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColor (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)I
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColor, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColor
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1087: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColor (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)I
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColorStateList
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1089: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColorStateList (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColorStateList
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1089: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColorStateList (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawable
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1096: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawable
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1096: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawableForDensity
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1098: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawableForDensity
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1098: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-15 21:07:32.389    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
06-15 21:07:32.419    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/DynamitePackage﹕ Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
06-15 21:07:32.419    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/DynamitePackage﹕ Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
06-15 21:07:32.469    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method aru.a
06-15 21:07:32.469    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 2392: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
06-15 21:07:32.469    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0072
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method brv.a
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1971: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method brv.a
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 523 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lbrv;
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0040
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lnx;.common_google_play_services_unknown_issue
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 4140 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lnx;
06-15 21:07:32.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0012
06-15 21:07:32.569    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lnx;.common_google_play_services_updating_text
06-15 21:07:32.569    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 4146 (common_google_play_services_updating_text) in Lnx;
06-15 21:07:32.569    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0021
06-15 21:07:32.569    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lnx;.common_google_play_services_updating_title
06-15 21:07:32.569    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x1033 at 0x2e in Lazx;.a
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 13
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 15
06-15 21:07:32.819    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 16
06-15 21:07:32.829    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 17
06-15 21:07:32.879    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/webclipboard﹕ clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41ba3480
06-15 21:07:32.889    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current, referenced from method ia.a
06-15 21:07:32.889    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8340: Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom;.current ()Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom;
06-15 21:07:32.889    9609-9663/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
06-15 21:07:32.929    9609-9616/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 18
06-15 21:07:33.249    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
06-15 21:07:33.249    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("315EA0C5061DFD25EBB0E5BC28752424") to get test ads on this device.
06-15 21:07:33.849    9609-9672/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample V/webkit﹕ BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41b9fa18}
06-15 21:07:33.899    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-15 21:07:33.979    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-15 21:07:33.999    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-15 21:07:34.009    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
    Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
06-15 21:07:34.499    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-15 21:07:36.979    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method avu.<init>
06-15 21:07:36.979    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2662: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
06-15 21:07:36.979    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0057
06-15 21:07:36.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method avu.evaluateJavascript
06-15 21:07:36.989    9609-9609/com.google.example.gms.ads.nativeexpressexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2672: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat?

Comment: You need to tell us more details than "the app not showing native ads"

Comment: pls check the edit @Isuru

Comment: @user3673952 chk the edit

Comment: what the heck where is those logcat and more detail guys?

Comment: Are you loading test ads? using following code, AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("315EA0C5061DFD25EBB0E5BC28752424")

Comment: yep am using that.

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. I have next logs from admob:  
>I: Starting ad request.
>I: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("241E542ADB6B0EDC7765DAAC7107523B") to get test ads on this device.
>W: Received error HTTP response code: 403
>W: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>W: Failed to load ad: 0  
It work only on test devices, but I'm not understand - can it work after release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem was there is not enough width on the screen to display native ads. When i removed the root Relative layout's margin left and margin right the ad started showing. In native ad Express we don't have much control over ad width that is the reason for this problem.